# c# file upload from memory

Tags: upload, memorystream

I have a piece of code to upload file from memory.

if  I use the method 1 (read file from disk) and then the code works fine. I can see the uploaded file from the testing server.

if I use method 2 (the way I want), use the data in memory , the file is not uploaded to the server.

I create the file from some library, it is in the memory_stream, I don't want to save it to disk and reload it to the memory. And the testing file from disk is created from the memory from the following code:

```
//code for savigng memory to file
if (AudioStream != null && AudioStream.Length > 0)
{
    string path = $"D:\\temp\\r_123.mp3";
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
    AudioStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    AudioStream.CopyTo(fs);
    fs.Close();
}



using (Stream AudioStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    // method 1 [working]
    //load into memory from file
    //using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"D:\Projects\T1.mp3"))
    //{
    //    fs.CopyTo(AudioStream);
    //}
    //end of method 1

    // method 2, not working
    memory_stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    memory_stream.CopyTo(AudioStream);
    // end of method 2

    AudioStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            using (var streamContent = new StreamContent(memory_stream))
            {
                using (var imageContent = new ByteArrayContent(streamContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result))
                {
                    imageContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");

                    form.Add(imageContent, "file", "cls.mp3");
                    var response = httpClient.PostAsync(to_url, form).Result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea about how to solve this? please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question. there is no issues about the file upload code.

The problem is the upload URL. the site is an asp.net site. it enabled the URL friendly setting. so there is NO .aspx at the end of URL.

if I post to the URL with .aspx, there will be no file. remove the aspx from the url the code will work just fine.

Comment: and there is no need to copy data from memorystream to a new memorystream.